# Why is Dropdownlist SelectedIndex always 0 when i come to the server code

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a usercontrol that gets opend as a dialog via script when i press a button.

Before this usercontroled is shown i populate the two dropdownlists that the usercontrol contains via an ajax call to the server.

I populate these two lists via jqyery and i set the selected index to the desierd values.

Inside the usercontrol i have a button that acts as a "buy" button and the two dropdownlists items are the products.

In my first server side check i check to see if the selectedindex of both the dropdownlists is 0 and for some reason it always is.

Jquery code:

```
 success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    $.each(data.List, function (key, value) {
                        $("#ctl00_mainAndRightContent_ctl00_SelectResourse_ResourceTypes").append('<option value=' + key + '>' + value + '</option>')

                        //if only one item is returned
                        if ($(data.List).length == 1) {
                            //$("#ctl00_mainAndRightContent_ctl00_SelectResourse_ResourceTypes option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
                            $("#ctl00_mainAndRightContent_ctl00_SelectResourse_ResourceTypes option:contains('" + value + "')").attr('selected', true).siblings().removeAttr('selected');
                            $("#ctl00_mainAndRightContent_ctl00_SelectResourse_ResourceTypes").prop('selectedIndex', 1);
                        }
                    });
                    $("#ctl00_mainAndRightContent_ctl00_SelectResourse_EducationTypes").append('<option value =' + data.Id + '>' + 'inserted' + '</option>')
                    $("#ctl00_mainAndRightContent_ctl00_SelectResourse_EducationTypes").prop('selectedIndex', 0);
                    $("#ctl00_mainAndRightContent_ctl00_SelectResourse_EducationTypes option").attr('selected', true);}
```

I get the desierd result after the ajax call but when i come to the serverside 
i see [This](http://s22.postimg.org/fgyfmbccx/Always0.jpg):

What am i missing here?

EDIT:

A pic of what i see in firebug [here](http://s11.postimg.org/xbu37m54z/More_Details.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apperently when you insert items via script the viewstate becomes obsolete and does not save the value.

I found the answer here:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1745879.aspx?Empty+value+DropDown+when+Postback+after+use+jquery+ajax

Answer (score -2):

Please check if those dropdownlist are having

```
runat=server
```

Comment: If you check the images and read the entier question you would realize that this answer is totaly out of scope. Of couarse they have runat="server" tag set.